# ERROR: Unable to parse parameter json file when trying to deploy bicep with GitHub Actions Workflow

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-bicep

I have been trying to deploy my bicep using parameters.json file privided in the inlineScript as shown below :

```
      - name: deploy
        uses: Azure/cli@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: "2.30.0"
          inlineScript: |
            az deployment group create \
              --resource-group my-resource-group \
              --name deploy-${{ github.run_id }} \
              --template-file ./Deployment/test.bicep \
              --parameters @./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json \
```

But It keeps giving me a parse error

```
Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.30.0
ERROR: Unable to parse parameter: ./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

I have followed the instructions provided by github [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameter-files.md) and the error persists.

And my paramters json file is also correctly formatted :

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "yourstorageaccountname"
        },
        "publicNetworkAccess": {
            "value": "Enabled"
        },
        "allowBlobPublicAccess": {
            "value": true
        },
        "allowSharedKeyAccess": {
            "value": true
        },
        "networkAclsDefaultAction": {
            "value": "Allow"
        },
        "dnsEndpointType": {
            "value": "Standard"
        },
        "keySource": {
            "value": "Microsoft.Storage"
        },
        "encryptionEnabled": {
            "value": true
        },
        "keyTypeForTableAndQueueEncryption": {
            "value": "Account"
        },
        "infrastructureEncryptionEnabled": {
            "value": false
        },
        "isContainerRestoreEnabled": {
            "value": false
        },
        "containerSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
            "value": 7
        },
        "isShareSoftDeleteEnabled": {
            "value": true
        },
        "shareSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
            "value": 7
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the complete workflow for better debugging:

```
name: Deploy MFT Core

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      main:
        description: Flag to compile main.bicep. True by default.
        required: false
        default: true
        type: boolean
      spoke:
        description: Flag to compile spoke.bicep. True by default.
        required: false
        default: true
        type: boolean
      notify:
        description: "Notify of deployments"
        required: true
        type: boolean
        default: false
      enviroment:
        description: "Environment"
        required: true
        type: environment
        default: "test"

env:
  LOCATION: "eastus"
jobs:
  checkout-branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{inputs.enviroment}}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository (with submodules)
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: "true"
          token: ${{ secrets.PLATFORM_PAT_TOKEN }}

  build-and-deploy:
    needs: checkout-branch
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{inputs.enviroment}}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository (with submodules)
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: "true"
          token: ${{ secrets.PLATFORM_PAT_TOKEN }}

      - name: Setup Bicep
        uses: anthony-c-martin/setup-bicep@v0.1

      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - name: Download actionlint
        id: get_actionlint
        run: bash <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rhysd/actionlint/main/scripts/download-actionlint.bash)
        shell: bash
      - name: Check workflow files
        run: ${{ steps.get_actionlint.outputs.executable }} -color
        shell: bash
      - name: deploy
        uses: Azure/cli@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: "2.39.0"
          inlineScript: |
            az deployment group create \
              --resource-group my-resource-group \
              --name deploy-${{ github.run_id }} \
              --template-file ./Deployment/test.bicep \
              --parameters @./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json \

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{inputs.enviroment}}
    steps:
      # Log into Azure
      - run: echo "Deploying to ${{vars.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER}} environment"
```

Comment: It's a parsing error. Did you try validating `azuredeploy.parameters.json`? You can lint it online using https://jsonlint.com/ or similar tools.

Comment: I've added my json file example , it's correctly formatted according to instrutions.

Comment: Right. Is that trailing \ there in your workflow at the end?

Comment: Yeah there is a trailing whitespace at the end of the line for `--parameters`

Comment: Whitespace or backslash \? Are there any other arguments too?

Comment: Please lint your complete workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/.

Comment: Each line ends with a whitespace and a backslash

Comment: Did the linting as well , there is no linting error

Comment: According to [`az deployment group create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-create), to pass the file with `--parameters` the syntax is `@{path}`. That makes sense as currently the path itself is being parsed as a JSON. Adding @ before your JSON file path should fix this issue.

Comment: Tried `  --parameters @"./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json"` and `  --parameters @./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json` , still the same result

Comment: Try it without quotes. Passing file path with with a preceding @ seems to be the correct syntax.

Comment: Doesn't work with or without the quotes `ERROR: Unable to parse parameter: @./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json`

Comment: Please include your complete workflow in your question. That'll be easier to reproduce.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/23854

Comment: It fails for any version of cli ```Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.39.0
ERROR: Unable to parse parameter: @./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json
Error: Error: az cli script failed.```

Comment: Please include your complete workflow in your question.

Comment: Remove that trailing backslash in the last line and test again.

Comment: Removed the trailing backslash and still getting the same error, for some reason it's not considering the `@./Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json` as a path , it's trying to parse it as if it's the actual paramters

Comment: Yes but not sure why. You might want to verify the steps from the docs again.

Comment: Everything was correct and apparently there was a hidden white space in the path and after typing it one more time it started working.

Comment: Right. Initially, I was about to ask you to verify the file path but then the error message was about parsing which was clearly misleading. Anyways, glad you could figure it out. Please also verify the @ part also to make sure whether it's needed or not as it's not there in the docs that you're following but it is there in the official Azure CLI docs.

Comment: It works with or without the `@`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path to parameters json file is incorrect it'd throw en error saying `Unable to parse json` which is confusing and very misguiding while the actual cause is that the file doesn't exist on that path. Correcting the path-to-json file resolves the issue.